# redirect pages after inserting values

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, insert

There is a two pages called Group_profile.php and group_create.php 
group_create.php  show the text fields after fill those fields then click the submit and i want to redirect the  Group_profile.php page.In group_create.php have some validations after checking the validations i want to redirect the Group_profile.php page.

my View

using this i insert values to db.this also contain my validation method

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action=<?php echo base_url('index.php/con_group_profile/insert');?> >
```

this is my submit button
    Create your Group Profile

my problen is where i want to put redirect code and what is redirect code.

Answer (score 2):

After your validation stuff just type:

```
header("Location: whereever.php");
exit;
```

As you have tagged the question with `codigniter` there is [a built-in way](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) as well (in your controller):

```
$this->load->helper('url');
redirect('/whereever/23');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
redirect(base_url().'controller/method'); # controller - name of your controller. # method - name of your method on controller
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not as helpful as answers that have working code plus helpful explanations. 
In this case, it would be worthwhile explaining this answer to a 5 year old.